# number of decoded frames in flash

Tags: flash, decode, netstream

Flash.net.netStream has an undocumented field called "decodedFrames" (which I discovered by reading someone's blog) This value is supposed to show how many frames have been decoded so far.

I wonder, since this is an undocumented field, can I rely on the correctness of this value?

Also, why isn't this documented? --I asked this question in the adobe's forum, but it seems like nobody is answering questions there. I hope someone knows the answer here.

Finally, if I am not supposed to rely on this value, what is the alternative to get this value?

This is flash's documentation on NetStream :
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder, since this is an undocumented field, can I rely on the
>   correctness of this value?

Yes. It does not fake the results...

> Also, why isn't this documented?

Because its only guaranteed to work correctly on desktops (not sure if mobile support has since been added)

> Finally, if I am not supposed to rely on this value, what is the
>   alternative to get this value?

Not much. You could try using [netStream.time](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#time) and assume if time is higher then frames must be decoded too. This measures time traveled within the video so you can break it down into frames if you wanted.